# Twitter share button is not working with Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, share

I use Jquery-Mobile & Phonegap to develop mobile applications. 
I want to share dynamic data using the twitter sharing script:

When I use this code in an external page "without using jquery-mobile or any other scripts, it works fine.

Html:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" 
data-url="http://your.url.com/yourdynamicpage" 
class="twitter-share-button" 
data-text="What should I share?" 
data-count="horizontal">Tweet</a>
```

But when I add this to the javascript file to add the info "Data-text" & "Data-Url" dynamically, twitter opens without this data inside it.

Html:

Javascript:

```
$('#TwitterShare').append('<a href="http://twitter.com/share" rel="external" 
data-url="http://your.url.com/yourdynamicpage" 
class="twitter-share-button" 
data-text="Dynamic Data will be inserted here" 
data-count="horizontal">Tweet</a>');
```

When I add the Lines statically, The link sent is :

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3025%2FShareTrial.html&source=tweetbutton&text=What%20should%20I%20share%3F&url=http%3A%2F%2Fyour.url.com%2Fyourdynamicpage
```

But when it's added dynamically, none of the data is sent at the link:

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3025%2FViewPost.html&url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3025%2FViewPost.html
```

I'm wondering why is this happening & how can I solve it ?

Thanks.